# JPA removing query with IdClass issue

Tags: java, jpa

When I use a Idclass in JPA for a entity with a composite key and I write a remove method like :

```
private static void removeEmployee(Employee employee) {
    EntityManagerFactory emf = Persistence
            .createEntityManagerFactory("JPA_excer_3b");
    EntityManager em = emf.createEntityManager();
    try {
        em.getTransaction().begin();
        Employee anemployee = em.find(Employee.class, employee.getId());
        em.remove(anemployee);
        em.getTransaction().commit();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        logging.error("This error is added a removing a employee :"
                + " :" + e);
    } finally {
        // Close all the connections:
        em.close();
        emf.close();
    }
}
```

I get the error :

```
ERROR Logger:22 - This error is added a removing a employee :java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Provided id of the wrong type for class be.leerstad.JPA.entities.Employee. Expected: class be.leerstad.JPA.entities.EmployeePK, got class java.lang.Integer
```

When I change the code to :

```
private static void removeEmployee(Employee employee) {
    EntityManagerFactory emf = Persistence
            .createEntityManagerFactory("JPA_excer_3b");
    EntityManager em = emf.createEntityManager();
    try {
        **EmployeePK pk = new EmployeePK(employee.getId(),employee.getEmail());**
        em.getTransaction().begin();
        Employee anemployee = em.find(Employee.class, **pk**);
        em.remove(anemployee);
        em.getTransaction().commit();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        logging.error("This error is added a removing a employee :"
                + " :" + e);
    } finally {
        // Close all the connections:
        em.close();
        emf.close();
    }
}
```

I don't get any errors but I wonder if this is the right way to do this?

Comment: Please share your entity and key class

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it's the right way to do it. The `EntityManager.find()` method expects an instance of the ID class of the entity. Not some random attribute of the entity.

Note that the error isn't caused by the `remove()` method, but by the `find()` method.